# How can I select all rows in a table a, which have n characteristics given in a table b

Tags: mysql, select

I'm making a web page for renting houses.

the publications are stored in a table like this

```
ta_publications
+---+-------------+------+
|id |    name     | date |
+---+-------------+------+
| 1 | name_001    |  ... |
| 2 | name_002    |  ... |
| 3 | name_003    |  ... |
+---+-------------+------+
```

I have diferent publications, which have "features" such as "satellite tv", "Laundry cleaning", etc.

These features might change in the future, and I want to be able to add/remove/modify them, so I store them in the database in a table.

```
ta_feature_types
+---+-------------+
|id | name        |
+---+-------------+
| 1 | Internet    |
| 2 | Wi-Fi       |
| 3 | satelital tv|
+---+-------------+
```

which are related to the publications using a table

```
ta_features
+---+-------------+----------------+
|id |   type_id   | publication_id |
+---+-------------+----------------+
| 1 |      1      |       1        |
| 2 |      2      |       1        |
| 3 |      3      |       1        |
+---+-------------+----------------+
```

I think it's pretty easy to understand; There is a publication called name_001 which have internet, wi-fi and satellite tv.

My problem is: I need to be able to efficiently search and select all publications(houses) wich have certain features. For example, all publications that have internet, wifi and "pets-allowed" features.

I just came up with another question: When the user likes one publication, say "house_003", how do I get a list of the features that it does have?

Comment: You don't need the ID column in `ta_features` unless a publication can have a feature multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get publications by feature *name*:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM ta_publications p
JOIN ta_features f ON f.publication_id = p.id
JOIN ta_feature_types t ON f.type_id = t.id
WHERE t.name = ? -- feature name
```

If you already know the feature *ID*:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM ta_publications p
JOIN ta_features f ON f.publication_id = p.id
WHERE f.type_id = ? -- feature ID
```

**EDIT:** To get all publications that match **all** of multiple feature IDs:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
FROM pub p
JOIN pub_feat pf ON pf.pub_id = p.id
WHERE pf.feat_id IN ? -- list of feature IDs, e.g. (1,2,3)
GROUP BY p.id, p.name HAVING COUNT(*) = ? -- size of list of feature IDs, e.g. 3
```

To get all the features (names, I assume) by publication ID:

```
SELECT t.name
FROM ta_feature_types t
JOIN ta_features f ON f.type_id = t.id
JOIN ta_publications p ON f.publication_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = ? -- publication ID
```

Some notes on your schema:

- As I commented above, you don't need an ID column in the `ta_features` table unless a publication can have the same features multiples times, e.g. "2x Wi-Fi"
- Your table names are confusing, may I suggest you rename

  - `ta_features` to `ta_publication_features` (or `ta_pub_features`) and
  - `ta_feature_types` to `ta_features`
- For performance reasons you should create indices on all the columns used in the above JOIN conditions (using your original table names here):

  - `ta_publications(id)`
  - `ta_features(type_id, publication_id)`
  - `ta_feature_types(id)`

Comment: "If you already know the feature ID:" it works, but only when looking for one feature. I need to be able to search publications with n-features, with n>=0 selected by the user.

Comment: Replace `WHERE f.type_id = ?` by `WHERE f.type_id IN ?` and set a list parameter.

Comment: I did tht, but it trows 3 times the same publication, one for each matched feature. Also, If I put two featues that the publication have and one that does not, it shows me 2 times the same publication (when it should not show it at all, since it doesn't match the search criteria)

Comment: My bad, that query returns a publication if it matches *any* given feature. I'll think of a query that matches publications with *all* given features.

Comment: `SELECT p.id, p.name FROM pub p JOIN pub_feat pf ON pf.pub_id = p.id WHERE pf.feat_id IN (1,2) GROUP BY p.id, p.name HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` -- this works but is ugly as hell. The `2` at the end is the *number of features* in the `IN` clause. (I shortened your table/column names but I should be clear what's what)

Comment: Mmmh, maybe the above query isn't that bad after all. It does what it's supposed in a single preparable query. Can't think of a better way right now.

Comment: I looked up and worked this out, but Im not sure if it is ok. I mean, it's not obvius and I guess there should be a better way to do this. (I am open to change my db structure if it's better that way)'
    SELECT *
    FROM ta_publicaciones AS pub
    WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT( * )
        FROM ta_features AS fea
        WHERE fea.id_publicacion = pub.id
        AND fea.id_tipo
        IN ( 1, 2, 4 )
    )=3
    LIMIT 0 , 30'

Comment: I'd recommend my `SELECT ... HAVING COUNT` over your query because it avoids that sub-select. Parameter-wise they're require the same effort  of setting a list and count.

Comment: Your schema is fine. One table per entity and one to relate them n:m.

Comment: ok. I guess it was ok, but just becouse your and mine query was weird, that there where a better table setting up. I want to really thank you for your help philipp, I'll sing-up to give you a vope up.

Answer (score 1):

If the user selects multiple features use the `IN` keyword and a list of all features for a publication:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM ta_publications p
WHERE '1' in (select type_id from ta_features where publication_id = p.id)
AND '2' in (select type_id from ta_features where publication_id = p.id)
AND '3' in (select type_id from ta_features where publication_id = p.id)
```

You could generate the above with a loop in your server language of choice. ie.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM ta_publications p
WHERE 1=1
//START SERVER LANGUAGE
for (feature in featuresArray){
    print("AND '$feature' in (select type_id from ta_features where publication_id = p.id)");
}
//END SERVER LANGUAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a subquery:

```
select a.* 
from ta_publications as a
where '1' in (select type_id from ta_features where publication_id=a.id)
```

Substitute '1' for any other feature number you want.

For your second question. A simple query should do it:

```
select type_id 
from ta_features
where publication_id=[[[id that someone likes]]]
```